# Wordpress permalink behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am running an AWS medium LAMP instance. I have three beta testing Wordpress sites all are running and rendering pages, none are 100% complete. Server software versions are:

php 7.0.3

httpd apache/2.4.33

Wordpress 4.9.8

I have spend considerable time researching my particular challenge, including writing some plugin code to attempt understanding the problem, I'm getting close but have not cracked the problem just yet.

The issue I am experiencing, is when I change my permalink settings to %postname% the site is unable to locate the pages. At this stage I am exclusively referencing only pages and not posts. I have not done any testing with posts.

I have confirmed that mod_rewrite is loaded using

```
sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
and
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The first command lists rewrite_module (shared) as present. The php script shows mod_rewrite as being part of the Loaded modules.

A good resource I followed was https://serverfault.com/questions/445599/enabling-mod-rewrite-on-amazon-linux. There were numerous others but this seemed to grasp all the salient points, that other searching brought up.

From the above I took the advice on testing redirection and it worked, routing one of my domains to wordpress.org. (to achieve this test i edited /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

> Please try this: In the server configuration - not .htaccess add the
>   lines RewriteEngine On and RewriteRule ^(.*)$
>   http://www.wordpress.org/ [R] to confirm if rewrite is functioning at
>   all. It should pass all traffic to the Wordpress website

Also I have created a basic plugin to test various WordPress functions. I thought that some internal misalignment might have caused WordPress not to find the requested page. This was wrong WordPress found the correct page when passing the page ID into the get_permalink() function.

I simply added an echo get_permalink(290); to my simple plugin code. And this correctly echoed

```
https://www.mydomainname.com/correct-slug-for-page-290
```

If I copy and paste the URL above it failed.

Note: When I modify my permalink settings the .htaccess file is automatically modified/updated.

If I set my WordPress permalink settings to plain, everything works.

If I set my WordPress permalink settings to custom and use index.php/%postname%/ all links resolve. (Both with and without .htaccess file present)

If I set my permalink settings to only %postname% everything becomes a 404 error. On setting to %postname% wordpress automatically creates the following file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache www 235 Sep  4 21:47 .htaccess 

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Snippets from my httpd.conf with most of the comments are edited out. I do plan on going back and tightening up some of the settings once I can get this base functionality to work.

Appreciate any insights, tips or suggestions. Thanks everyone.

```
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"


Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf


User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>


<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@beta-test-one.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/beta-test-one.com
    ServerName beta-test-one.com
    ServerAlias www.beta-test-one.com
    RewriteEngine On
    <IF "req('Host') != 'www.beta-test-one.com'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IF>
    <ELSE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </ELSE>
    ErrorLog logs/beta-test-one.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/beta-test-one.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@beta-test-two.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/beta-test-two.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/beta-test-two.com">
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerName beta-test-two.com
    ServerAlias www.beta-test-two.com
    RewriteEngine On
    <IF "req('Host') != 'www.beta-test-two.com'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IF>
    <ELSE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </ELSE>
    ErrorLog logs/beta-test-two.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/beta-test-two.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@beta-test-three.com.au
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/beta-test-three.com.au
    ServerName beta-test-three.com.au
    ServerAlias www.beta-test-three.com.au
    RewriteEngine On
    <IF "req('Host') != 'www.beta-test-three.com.au'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </IF>
    <ELSE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    </ELSE>
    ErrorLog logs/beta-test-three.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/beta-test-three.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved.

I started reviewing my mod_rewrite setup. I realized that I had tested from within the httpd.conf file but not tested redirection at the .htaccess level following some tips from the following article,

> https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works

It ended up that the .htaccess file was being bypassed.

The ultimate culprit were the explicit re-directs to https in the httpd.conf file

```
 RewriteEngine On <IF "req('Host') != 'www.beta-test-three.com.au'">
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http RewriteRule .*
 https://www.%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] </IF> <ELSE>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http RewriteRule .*
 https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] </ELSE>
```

I removed these lines and tested again… The standard WordPress permalinks are all resolving. I had initially added those lines because when I had been typing domain-name.com (without the https prefix) I was getting browser messages that the site is not secure.

However by updating the wp-config file as follows (see below) I don’t need the https redirection in the httpd.conf file and this has allowed the .htaccess rewrite rules to work.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.domain-name.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.domain-name.com');

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```