# I don’t understand the behaviour on Apache server redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes, url-routing

All my sites sit behind an AWS load balancer. I have asked a related question on rewrites on Stack Overflow forums,  if you want more information on the background check [Wordpress permalink behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175150/wordpress-permalink-behavior/52285687#52285687)

I had solved this initial problem myself by moving redirection out of the Apache httpd.conf file. I am forced to revisit after checking my site performance.

The problem in a nutshell is that if I re-direct in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
<IF "req('Host') != 'www.beta-test-three.com.au'">
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IF>
<ELSE>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</ELSE>
```

My home page on sitename.com displays and is super fast. Unfortunately for some reason my URL rewrites in my .htaccess file are bypassed. The rules below allow me to show nice URLs without having index.php on every  link e.g. sitename.com?index.php/page-name rather it allows for all pages to display as sitename.com/page-name

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Now the reason I really want the re-direction to happen via httpd.conf is that my site load time goes from 2.9s to 1.8s I save over one second!

I just don't understand why when I turn on the redirects in httpd.conf then my .htaccess rewrite rules get deactivated?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was to add the following to the VirtualHosts section in httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/site-name">
 AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

I have responded with more detail at the WordPress support forms
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/i-dont-understand-the-behaviour-on-apache-server-redirection/

Thanks and regards.